# else block of if-else acting differently to different conditions

Tags: hardware, verilog, fpga, hdl

I'm coding a simple shift register using if else block. I noticed that the else block works as it should when the control signal is `control = 2'b00` (meaning it retains the default vale) but when I give the control value `control = 2'b11` it starts shifting to the right, which is not what I want.

Why does the else block work selectively? Even when both `control = 2'b00` and `control = 2'b11` fall in the else case?

Code and screenshot below:

```
module shift(
input clock,
input reset,
input [1:0] control,
input in,
output [7:0] out
);

reg [7:0] r_reg, r_next; //a 7 bit shift register which will be output as is, this can be changed to any size

always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)
begin
    if(reset)
        r_reg <= 0;
    else
        r_reg <= r_next;
end

always @ (*)

begin

if(control[0]) //shift right
    r_next = {in, r_reg[7:1]};

else if(control[1]) //shift left
    r_next = {r_reg[6:0], in};

else
    r_next = r_reg; //default state stays the same

end

assign out = r_reg;

endmodule
```

[image]

EDIT:

```
if(right) //shift right
    r_next = {in, r_reg[7:1]};

else if(left) //shift left
    r_next = {r_reg[6:0], in};

else if((~right & ~left) || (right & left))
    r_next = r_reg; //default state stays the same
```

The above did not work either.. But I fixed it with case.

```
case(control)
    2'b01: r_next = {in, r_reg[7:1]};
    2'b10: r_next = {r_reg[6:0], in};
    default: r_next = r_reg;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple: It doesn't fall in the else case at all.

Your first condition looks only at the low bit (matches b'd1), therefore both b'01 and b'11 shift right.

Comment: thanks. I managed to add more control using case.. Though I would still like to know why it did not work with the added edit of if else in my original post?

Comment: @ipunished: You didn't show your equation for `right` and `left`, but it looks to me like you made the exact same mistake as at the beginning.  By that I mean, your logic is setup to shift right if `right` is set, without caring what value `left` has.

Comment: hmmm..I assume you are talking about my edit regarding the if else and not the case.. So is this what you mean: ``if(right && ~left) //shift right``? If not can you please give an example of what you mean by " not caring for ``left`` value. Thank you

Comment: @ipunished: Yes, `right & ~left` is the condition you needed to use.

Answer (score 2):

`control[0]` is `1` when you input `11`, so I think it's working as expected.  You'd need a stronger condition to make it work the way you seem to want:

```
if (control == 2'b01)          // shift right
    r_next = {in, r_reg[7:1]};

else if (control == 2'b10)     // shift left
    r_next = {r_reg[6:0], in};

else                           // default state stays the same
    r_next = r_reg;
```

Comment: Thanks.. I added further control by using the code in the edit above but that did not work either but now I have fixed it with case.

Comment: Your code in your edit has exactly the same problem... Good to hear you've fixed it.